# What to build with [lego]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently our [lego](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego) tag (and related tags) are <s>a mess</s> something that can probably be fixed fairly easily given that there are around thirty questions overall ([this query](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego+or+lego-%2A+or+%2A-lego+or+%2A-lego-%2A+or+bionicle), courtesy of @SQB, yields 32 results).

Furthermore the tag description for [lego](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego) is misleading:

> Lego is a line of plastic construction toys that are manufactured by The Lego Group. Questions which ask for identification of SF and fantasy toys built with Lego are on-topic, any others are not, and belong on bricks.SE.

... yet only 6 [lego](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego) questions (out of 16) are ID.

This could be the occasion to assemble a tagging policy for LEGO-related tags.

Hence, **what to build with LEGO?**

---

For the record, our current other LEGO tags are [lego-star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-star-wars), [lego-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-cinematic-universe), [the-lego-batman-movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-lego-batman-movie), [the-lego-movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-lego-movie), [the-lego-ninjago-movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-lego-ninjago-movie) and [bionicle](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bionicle).

Comment: I think we have jumped the shark with the gimmick tag titles.

Answer (score 9):

## First MOC

**TL;DR:**

- [lego](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego) - on everything
- [lego-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-cinematic-universe) - on LCU works, always use with [lego](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego) and work
- [lego-work](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-work) - about the work - always use with [lego](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego) and [lego-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-cinematic-universe) (if appropriate)

---

I propose

- using [lego](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego) as the "general" tag; it will be use on *all* LEGO questions. The rationale is that someone looking for [lego](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego) stuff might be remotely interested in other LEGO-related tags. ID questions would then be tagged [lego](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego)+[character-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-identification) or [lego](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego)+[object-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/object-identification), and tag description would be edited in consequence. *16 questions to retag*
- using [lego-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-cinematic-universe) for this universe (duh), the way [dc-extended-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-extended-universe) or [marvel-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe) work. The idea is to encompass current movies/games/shorts in this universe while excluding [lego-star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-star-wars)-like tags (which, as far as I know, aren't part of the LCU); *6 questions to retag*
- using [lego](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego)+[relevant-lego-tag](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/relevant-lego-tag) for other works. [*8 questions to retag*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bionicle+or+lego-star-wars+-lego)

Cross-universe cases:

- tag [the-lego-batman-movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-lego-batman-movie) with [dc](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc) too, as [there's a DC stamp to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkdRT.jpg);
- tag [lego-star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-star-wars) with both [lego](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego) and [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) for the same reason.

Seems fairly in line with what's done with other materials/franchises, and (though my figures might be slightly off) the amount of retagging involved can probably be done smoothly over a week or so.

Comment: What's a *MOC*?

Comment: @Randal'Thor My Own Creation, which is what AFoLs (Adult Fans of Lego) call models they designed themselves.

Comment: Re cross-universe cases: Lots of [these things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Lego_video_games#Licensed_properties) look on-topic to me... Do we need a general system for handling them?

Comment: (For example, should we create [tag:lego-adaptation-game] or something?  I should point out that all of these games are basically the same game but with different window dressing.)

Comment: @Kevin we have [lego-star-wars], I can imagine [lego-harry-potter] or [lego-harry-potter], tagged along with [Lego] and [franchise]. Not like there will be tons of them in the years to come, I think

Comment: @Jenayah: LOTR, Marvel, and DC all already have games and they have more lined up for 2019.

Comment: @Kevin sorry, I was unclear; I meant there wouldn't be a heckton of _questions_ about those.

Comment: FWIW there are LEGO Star Wars short films so that could be what the tag is used for but I haven't looked.

Comment: Can you make it explicit whether we should use [lego] on questions about Lego Harry Potter video games and Lego Star Wars video games? We don't seem to have any clear examples yet, but  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/85804/4918 https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/41192/4918 ask about multiple video games, including lego ones.

Comment: @b_jonas I'd say both of those can use either the relevant [lego-game-tag] or just [video-games] as they cover even non-Lego ones. Sometimes we should look on a case-by-case basis, of course

Comment: there was an entire Lego Star Wars series as well - but I think it was officially declared as non-canon (Freemaker Adventures)